# Why my code doesn't run when I reboot the raspberry?

Tags: raspbian, python, script

So to start in what I tried. first this is the code that I wrote to run

```
import subprocess
import pyautogui
import urllib.request
import time

while(1):
    x = str(pyautogui.position())
    time.sleep(120)
    try:
        urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.com')
        notconnected = "False"
    except:
            notconnected = "True"
    y = str(pyautogui.position())
    if(x == y and notconnected == "True"):
        subprocess.call(["sudo","shutdown","now"])
```

Then I went to terminal and wrote this command to run when reboot

```
 sudo crontab -e
```

and I wrote on the last line of the file

```
@reboot python /home/pi/shutdown.py &
```

**Note: the code runs successfully when I run on it terminal.**

Comment: Your code makes network requests. Are you sure it is executed after network functionality is available? If it runs before then it will fail. Therefore I would recommend to run it via systemd service and add as requirement that network is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding 3 after python 
this line before the edit
`@reboot python /home/pi/shutdown.py &`
and after the edit 
`@reboot python3 /home/pi/shutdown.py &`
so be careful that when you write python only you mean 2.x but when you write python3 you are saying python 3.x
hope this answer is clear